# Initialization of a templated data member cryptic error

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, compiler-errors

This is my `tmp.hpp`:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct int_int_hasher {
  size_t operator()(pair<int, int> const& p) const {
    return static_cast<size_t>(p.first) << 32 | p.second;
  }
};

template<class T, class H>
class BiBag {
  unordered_map<T, uint, H> t_to_id_;
};
```

And simple `tmp.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "tmp.hpp"

class tmp {
  BiBag<pair<int, int>, int_int_hasher> tt =
    BiBag<std::pair<int, int>, int_int_hasher>();
};
```

The error message is beyond my understanding:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 tmp.cpp -lm -o tmp
tmp.cpp:6:32: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     BiBag<std::pair<int, int>, int_int_hasher>();
                                ^
tmp.cpp:6:32: error: declaration of ‘BiBag<std::pair<int, int>, int_int_hasher> tmp::int_int_hasher’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from tmp.cpp:2:0:
tmp.hpp:7:8: error: changes meaning of ‘int_int_hasher’ from ‘struct int_int_hasher’ [-fpermissive]
 struct int_int_hasher {
        ^
tmp.cpp:6:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
     BiBag<std::pair<int, int>, int_int_hasher>();
                                              ^
tmp.cpp:6:16: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     BiBag<std::pair<int, int>, int_int_hasher>();
                ^
```

If I remove the hasher from the picture and replace the map with a simple `<int,int>` map I get no error.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug. The code looks good to me, and clang and MSVC compile it fine.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xuO6kmA4aYM11ZG7) as of gcc6. Upgrade your compiler. The code is fine, pre-gcc6 is buggy.

Comment: Ah. That was it. Upgraded to 6.2 and it worked. It cost me some hair. Thank you.