# using typedef-ed type as class template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, typedef

I have the following code:

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

template<typename K, typename V>
class A {
    K a;
    V b;

public:
    A() {}
};

class B {
private:
    A<uint64, uint64>* a = new A<uint64, uint64>(); // does not compile
    A<uint64, uint64>* b = new A<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>(); // does compile
};

int main() {
    new B();
    return 0;
}
```

This however for some reason does not compile and gives a lot of unrelated (in my opinion) and different errors across all the files. (The complete list of them is at the end of the question)

But if I replace the **uint64** in the A constructor invocation with **unsigned long long** the code magically compiles and all the errors disappear. What is even more strange is that the same code compiles on some compilers but not on this one.

What is the reason for this behaviour? Why is this happening? And how can I write the class to be compilable on different compilers?

---

I am using CMake which is using c++:

```
$ c++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
```

Complete list of errors:

```
main.cpp:16:42: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     A<uint64, uint64>* a = new A<uint64, uint64>(); // does not compile
                                          ^
main.cpp:16:42: error: declaration of ‘A<long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int> B::uint64’ [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:3:28: error: changes meaning of ‘uint64’ from ‘typedef long long unsigned int uint64’ [-fpermissive]
 typedef unsigned long long uint64;
                            ^
main.cpp:16:48: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
     A<uint64, uint64>* a = new A<uint64, uint64>(); // does not compile
                                                ^
main.cpp:16:34: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     A<uint64, uint64>* a = new A<uint64, uint64>(); // does not compile
                                  ^
main.cpp:6:7: error: provided for ‘template<class K, class V> class A’
 class A {
       ^
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41435064/580083

Comment: My guess would be, the definition of `uint64` is not in fact visible in the place where you are trying to use it.

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The error message says otherwise: _error: changes meaning of ‘uint64’ from ‘typedef long long unsigned int uint64’..._.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The types.h file is included in all other files, so the type should be visible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought the minimal complete verifiable example was clear from the question. I edited the question - removed all names and unrelated errors.

Comment: @MatejKormuth It doesn't compile with GCC 4 and 5. It does compile with GCC 6 and higher. Seems to be a compiler bug. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ufSZB4ZlguWz7UOE

Comment: Miles better now, thank you. The previous version was not at all a MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid (and works for me); this is a compiler bug. Quite a nasty one at that!

From a little bisection on Godbolt, it looks dodgy going right back to 4.8 (prior to that you're going to struggle to get those NSDMIs working anyway!), and if you use GCC 6 or higher you should be fine.

Comment: I did have a quick look in Bugzilla for a ref#, but haven't found a match so far